# Smallest Collection for Serialization

Tags: java, performance, serialization, collections, vector

I have a Java app, (Fat Client, Server, Database).  All server method calls return a Vector (the server code was originally built years ago, and has been left the same for consistency).  The Vector ALWAYS returns 2 positions no mater what the call.  The first position is an error object(or null) to alert the client of any issues the server had while processing the method call.  The second position is the data we want.  It could be an ArrayList of Objects, a String, int, ect; whatever the fat client is looking for.

I'm trying to reduce the footprint and increase performance of my server calls.  One thing I'm looking at is removing the returning Vectors and replacing them with something.  My question is what.  As stated, this collection will always be 2 positions long, have position 0 as an error object (null if no error), and position 1 as "my data".  It never needs to be sorted, it's basically used for a method that returns 2 parameters (and serializes them as it is going from server to client).

I need no functionality other then transporting position 0 and 1 to the client as, once this collection hits the client, position 0 is examined for errors and position 1 is pulled out and handed off to the calling piece of code as whatever object was stored there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If ya "trying to reduce the footprint and increase performance of my server calls", then what is the performance bottleneck? It sure is not the array vehicle. Don't optimize a thing until you know the top 5 performance bottlenecks, from end to end.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class:

```
class MeaningfulNameForTheResult
{
  public Error error;
  public Object result;
}
```

and use that as a result.

Depending an your needs make the properties private or not and add setters/getters or not,... but the general idea: Create a class with two properties that you serialize.

Edit: Maybe... Depending on your needs you can even just remove that object completely. Just return your desired result object if everything is alright and return an error object if something is wrong. In the client, unserialize the object and then check the type. If it is `instanceof Error` then you know it's an error, it's your result otherwise.